# How to create circular CGRect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using this code to create the rectangle in my app. But i want to make it rounded. How can i do that.

```
- (void)setCropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
    if(!CGRectEqualToRect(_cropRect,cropRect)){
        _cropRect = CGRectOffset(cropRect, self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.f);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(self.bounds);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5].CGColor);
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, cropRect);
        [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(CGRectInset(cropRect, 1, 1));
        self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

I am using this code to crop the image in rectangular shape:

```
- (CGImageRef)newTransformedImage:(CGAffineTransform)transform
                     sourceImage:(CGImageRef)sourceImage
                    sourceSize:(CGSize)sourceSize
           sourceOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)sourceOrientation
                 outputWidth:(CGFloat)outputWidth
                    cropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
               imageViewSize:(CGSize)imageViewSize
{
    CGImageRef source = sourceImage;

    CGAffineTransform orientationTransform;
    [self transform:&orientationTransform andSize:&imageViewSize forOrientation:sourceOrientation];

    CGFloat aspect = cropRect.size.height/cropRect.size.width;
    CGSize outputSize = CGSizeMake(outputWidth, outputWidth*aspect);

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                 outputSize.width,
                                                 outputSize.height,
                                                 CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(source),
                                                 0,
                                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(source),
                                                 CGImageGetBitmapInfo(source));
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,  [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, outputSize.width, outputSize.height));

    CGAffineTransform uiCoords = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(outputSize.width/cropRect.size.width,
                                                            outputSize.height/cropRect.size.height);
    uiCoords = CGAffineTransformTranslate(uiCoords, cropRect.size.width/2.0, cropRect.size.height/2.0);
    uiCoords = CGAffineTransformScale(uiCoords, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, uiCoords);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, orientationTransform);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-imageViewSize.width/2.0,
                                           -imageViewSize.height/2.0,
                                           imageViewSize.width,
                                           imageViewSize.height)
                       ,source);



    CGImageRef resultRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    return resultRef;
}
```

Is i can use the brazier curve to crop the image also.

Comment: I think you mean "how do I make a circular crop"? A CGRect is just a struct that is made up of an origin and size.

Comment: @CrimsonChris You are right, But i am using this code for rectangle crop and its good, So i thought that if i can modify this code for circular crop.

Comment: you can simply add [self.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:self.imageView.frame.size.width/2.0]; and import QuartzCore

Comment: @iphonic But it will make imageview circular but i want to crop the image in circle. As i sending this image on server which can use it to display it in profile. So i need to make imge croped in circle not circular imageview.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a “circular CGRect”, or a rounded CGRect (which is what you appear to actually want).  A CGRect has an origin and a width and a height.  It doesn't store any corner radiuses (radii).

Instead of using `UIRectFill`, you need to create a `UIBezierPath` of a rounded rect and then fill the path.  Example:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:10];
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
[path fill];
```

You can also stroke a path if you need to.  Example:

```
path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cropRect cornerRadius:10];
path.lineWidth = 10;
[[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] setStroke];
[path stroke];
```

Comment: Thank you rob its draw the circle but how could i crop the image according to this circle? I have added my cropping code.+1

Comment: Check out the `addClip` method of `UIBezierPath`.